# PHP + Apache + parallel processing

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, fork

This is taking me a lot of days but no luck…
Apache 2.4.25
PHP 7.3.9

I need to some tasks to be run in parallel (in concrete, some ICMP pings…).

After a lot of research i’ve managed to create a php that runs the tasks in parallel. But it works in CLI, not as apache module.

After a lot a searchs and browsing it seems that in this enviroment

pthreads is not available?
pcntl_fork is not available?
is there any way to get this work?

Thanks all!

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/), pcntl_fork will not work if PHP is being run as an Apache module, however you may want to look into using the [Thread](https://www.php.net/thread) class.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried to use it but it seems it is also not available by default. It needs php to be compiled with threads enabled...
Im surprised there are so many difficulteis in doing this...

Comment: Try using Swoole.

Comment: @JaviS You don't compile PHP with threads enabled, you add the PECL `threads` module (`pecl install pthreads`).

Comment: If ZTS is not an issue you  can check out https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTM-Async/blob/master/Docs/Examples/Parallel/README.md